# org.quartz.SchedulerException: Jobs added with no trigger must be durable

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I am useing SpringBoot 2.1.5 with Quartz Starter.

This is my Job

```java
@Slf4j
public class LogJob extends QuartzJobBean {
    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        log.info("hello world");
    }
}
```

Just a very simple job, It logs some message.

Then, They are my configuration beans:

```java
@Configuration
public class QuartzJobConfig {
    @Bean
    public JobDetail issuesSyncJobDetail(){
        return JobBuilder.newJob(LogJob.class)
                .withIdentity("vue", "vuejsJob")
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public Trigger triggerIssuesJob(JobDetail jobDetail){
        int interval = 2;
        SimpleScheduleBuilder scheduleBuilder = SimpleScheduleBuilder
                .simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(interval).repeatForever();

        return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .forJob(jobDetail)
                .withIdentity("vue","vuejsTrigger")
                .withSchedule(scheduleBuilder).startNow().build();
    }
}
```

I create a JobDetatil Bean and a  trigger, I expect it should works.

But When I start my Project, it throw an error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzScheduler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/quartz/QuartzAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerException: Jobs added with no trigger must be durable.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:824) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.github.fish56.issues.IssuesApplication.main(IssuesApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.quartz.SchedulerException: Jobs added with no trigger must be durable.
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.addJob(QuartzScheduler.java:934) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.addJob(QuartzScheduler.java:927) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.addJob(StdScheduler.java:268) ~[quartz-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor.addJobToScheduler(SchedulerAccessor.java:284) ~[spring-context-support-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor.registerJobsAndTriggers(SchedulerAccessor.java:226) ~[spring-context-support-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:504) ~[spring-context-support-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

How to fix `org.quartz.SchedulerException: Jobs added with no trigger must be durable.`?

I think I already a trigger for the job....

Answer (score 10):

I find a solution:

```java
    @Bean
    public JobDetail issuesSyncJobDetail(){
        return JobBuilder.newJob(IssuesSyncJob.class)
                .withIdentity("vue", "vuejsJob")
                .storeDurably(true) // here!!!!!
                .build();
```

I should set Durably to `true` when I use builder to create JobDetail.

From [official documentation](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/JobBuilder.html#storeDurably())

```
/* Whether or not the Job should remain stored after it is orphaned (no Triggers point to it). If not explicitly set, the default value is false this method sets the value to true.*/

public JobBuilder storeDurably(return storeDurably(true);)
public JobBuilder storeDurably(boolean jobDurability)
```

Comment: Or just `.storeDurably()`. This will set it to `true`.